# Does the DocuSign Intermediate API plan let me use the API to get PDF and form fields?

Tags: docusignapi

I tried calling DocuSign sales and support (transferred around 3 times) and no one could give me a straight answer on this. Their "support" actually told be to try stackoverflow, so here I am...

I'm looking at their API pricing levels here: https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing/api-plans-b

**If I have the Intermediate API, can I make the following API requests?**

> GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}
>
> GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/form_data

The part that's throwing me for a loop is the DocuSign Connect feature in the Advanced API plan. The description of it is:

> The DocuSign Connect module lets you configure webhooks for envelope events and recipient actions for some or all users in your account. It can also be used to **transport the completed documents** back to your app or website and to **retrieve any form field data** entered by your recipients.

I don't need the webhooks, but I need to be able to get the completed documents as PDFs and get the form field data. Do I really need the DocuSign Connect feature for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be fine with the intermediate plan. Here is the basic distinction between polling and Connect - With Connect, we will proactively notify YOU when key envelope events occur.

Otherwise, it's up to you to call GET /envelopes and/or GET /form_data to retrieve that information. Be wary of the [resource limits](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/resource-limits) when you poll.

As a quick aside, instead of making two requests to retrive that information, just make one - `GET /envelopes?include=recipients,tabs`. This will provide you all the information you seek in one request.

The important excerpt from that guide:

> You may not exceed one GET request per unique envelope endpoint per 15
>   minutes. If you exceed this limit the request will not fail, but it
>   will be flagged as a violation of rate limits which can cause your app
>   to fail review to go-live review.

For example, the following transactions violate API rules due to the repeated GET requests to the first document and second recipient:

```
[12:00:00] POST /accounts/12345/envelopes
[12:01:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/documents/1
[12:02:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/recipients/2
[12:03:00] POST /accounts/12345/envelopes
[12:04:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/documents/1 *
[12:05:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/recipients/2 *
```

However, the following set of requests comply with API rules and limits and would not be flagged by the platform:

```
[12:00:00] POST /accounts/12345/envelopes
[12:01:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA
[12:16:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA
[12:17:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/documents/1 
[12:32:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/documents/1 
[12:40:00] PUT  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/recipients/1
[12:41:00] PUT  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/recipients/1
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the java SDK. Is there a class/method that would do the same thing as `/envelopes?include=recipients,tabs`?

Comment: Envelopes::getEnvelope - https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/130c9cca89b3467e7c2bf9d76f612e57511b9500/src/main/java/com/docusign/esign/api/EnvelopesApi.java#L3386

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-downloading-documents/ blog post with code snippets in 6 langs, including Java